# Method overloading - reference to is ambiguous

Tags: java, overloading

I'm trying to get better grips of function overloading.

I've this test program (pardon me for my C inspired Java).

```
public class Test {
    static void f(int x, double y)
    {
        System.out.printf("%d, %f",x,y);
    }

    static void f(double x, int y)
    {
        System.out.printf("%f, %d", x, y);
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {

    f(1, 2);

    }
}
```

now if I call,

```
f(1, 2);
```

There is compiler error,   `*reference to f is ambiguous*`

Why this error?  Are we not calling `f(int, int)`?  But no such method is declared.  I was expecting  "no suitable method found for f" instead, but I did not get one, why?

Comment: "I'm also interested to know what results C++ and C#" Thats something you can try yourself.

Comment: The problem is not that there is no suitable method, it's that there are two of them and neither is a better match (according to Java's rules) to the actual call arguments than the other.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`int` is convertible to `double` in all of these languages, so if only *one* of them were available, it would be easy: convert whichever value needs to be converted to a `double`, and call the method.

But in this case, *both* methods are "valid" in that each would be fine on its own - but neither is "better" than the other, because in each case one argument only needs the identity `int` to `int` conversion, and the other needs the `int` to `double` conversion. So in both Java and C# it's ambiguous and will fail with a compile-time error. I'd *imagine* that's what it does in C++ too, but I don't know for sure. In both Java and C#, if you had *also* a method `static void f(int x, int y)`, that would unambiguously be better than either of the other two, for that method invocation.

When in doubt, you should consult the relevant language specifications. For Java, [JLS section 15.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) is the relevant part. In the [C# 5 specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), it's section 7.5.

Comment: Thanks, and checking from spec is a nice idea, never thought that.

Answer (score 1):

you have these functions that are awfully close to each other or better sense ambiguous for the compiler to understand  so compilers gets confused to see these

```
static void f(int x, double y)

static void f(double x, int y)
```

In order to get rid of this confusion or ambiguity for the compiler simple add following

```
 static void f(int x, int y)
```

I think this comment explain it better for you

> The problem is not the lack of a method that has two int parameters.
>   The problem is that there are two methods that are equally good
>   matches according to Java's rules for matching method calls to
>   methods. Eliminate one of the existing f() methods and the error will
>   go away. –  **Ted Hopp**

Comment: that is what I'm not getting. We don't have f(int, int). Doesn't that mean we don't have this method at all, and so I was expecting a 'method not found'.

Comment: when you do not have it in your code, simply you donot have it. you have to define it so you can have it

Comment: The problem is not the lack of a method that has two int parameters. The problem is that there are two methods that are equally good matches according to Java's rules for matching method calls to methods. Eliminate one of the existing `f()` methods and the error will go away.

Comment: @Tedhopp you are totally right when I saw the code, I dawned on to me :)

Comment: @AbdullahLeghari did you get it? I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for updated answer Kick, it makes some sense now.

Answer (score 1):

In `f(1, 2);` both numbers can be interpreted as either `int` or `double`, so it's ambiguous. You can clarify by writing like this:

```
f(1., 2);
```

or

```
f(1d, 2);
```

However, it's not a good practice to overload a method with multiple signatures that have the same number of parameters. It's a good practice to avoid such overloadings as much as possible.

A classic example of how things can go wrong with overloading with same number of parameters, from Joshua Bloch's Effective Java:

```
public class CollectionClassifier {
   public static String classify(Set<?> s) {
       return "Set";
   }
   public static String classify(Collection<?> c) {
       return "Unknown Collection";
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Collection<?>[] collections = {
           new HashSet<String>(),
           new ArrayList<BigInteger>()
       };
       for (Collection<?> c : collections) {
           System.out.println(classify(c));
       }
   }
}
```

This will print `Unknown Collection` twice, and it can be easy to overlook.